# Check all checkboxes that are children of parent checkbox - multiple parents

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have checkboxes that are nested in the list. How can I check all checkboxes that are children of a parent? So when the test_2 is checked qqa and qwea is checked also.

```html
<ul class="folder-container">
  <li class="file-item colapse">
    <input class="fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox">test_1
  
  </li>
  <ul class=" folder-container" style="">
    <ul class="folder-container">
      <li class="file-item">
        <input class="fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox" value="qqa1.txt">qqa.txt
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="folder-container">
      <li class="file-item">
        <input class=" fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox" value="qwea1.txt">qwea.txt
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>

<ul class="folder-container">
  <li class="file-item colapse">
    <input class="fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox">test_2
  
  </li>
  <ul class=" folder-container" style="">
    <ul class="folder-container">
      <li class="file-item">
        <input class="fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox" value="qqa.txt">qqa2.txt
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="folder-container">
      <li class="file-item">
        <input class=" fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox" value="qwea.txt">qwea2.txt
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: [(javascript OR jquery) checkbox ("check all" OR "select all")](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%28javascript+OR+jquery%29+checkbox+%28%22check+all%22+OR+%22select+all%22%29+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: I suggest you add an event listener to the parent input and getting reference to the 2 checkboxes , the callback should make it the opposite 
make sure you give and id to the checkbox
`document.getElementById("checkbox-id").checked = true;`

Comment: Your markup is invalid. `<ul>` is not a valid child of `<ul>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample provided based on your html.

> Whether you use the *class* attribute, the *relative position* of the
> element or the *id*, the most important thing is that you know how to
> catch the parents and how to catch the corresponding children.
>
> When you know who the children are, you can use the parent's status to update the status of the children.

```js
const $parents =
  $('.folder-container li:first input[type=checkbox]');

$parents.on('change', function(){
  const $childes = $(this).closest('li').next('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]');
  $childes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="folder-container">
  <li class="file-item colapse">
    <input class="fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox" >test_2
   </li>
  <ul class=" folder-container" style="">
    <ul class="folder-container">
      <li class="file-item">
        <input class="fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox" value="qqa.txt">qqa.txt
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="folder-container">
      <li class="file-item">
        <input class=" fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox" value="qwea.txt">qwea.txt
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

---

Here is an example based on your html for multiple checkboxes.

> Like I said before, when you determine who is the parent, you can
> easily find the corresponding child.
>
> So just replace:
>
> ```
> $('.folder-container li:first input[type=checkbox]');
> ```
>
> With:
>
> ```
> $('.folder-container .colapse input[type=checkbox]');
> ```

```js
const $parents =
  $('.folder-container .colapse input[type=checkbox]');

$parents.on('change', function() {
  const $childes = $(this).closest('li').next('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]');
  $childes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="folder-container">
  <li class="file-item colapse">
    <input class="fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox">test_1

  </li>
  <ul class=" folder-container" style="">
    <ul class="folder-container">
      <li class="file-item">
        <input class="fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox" value="qqa1.txt">qqa.txt
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="folder-container">
      <li class="file-item">
        <input class=" fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox" value="qwea1.txt">qwea.txt
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>

<ul class="folder-container">
  <li class="file-item colapse">
    <input class="fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox">test_2

  </li>
  <ul class=" folder-container" style="">
    <ul class="folder-container">
      <li class="file-item">
        <input class="fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox" value="qqa.txt">qqa2.txt
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="folder-container">
      <li class="file-item">
        <input class=" fileModalCHx SWCheckBox markings" type="checkbox" value="qwea.txt">qwea2.txt
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```